# Calling Akavache synchronously causes deadlock

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, akavache

I am trying to use Akavache's `BlobCache.InMemory.GetOrCreateObject` to add caching to one of my database table, when I call it asynchronously, everything is fine. But since async requires caller to change to async as well and there are a lot of places to change, so I opt to call `BlobCache.InMemory.GetOrCreateObject` synchronously instead by doing something like below

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetAllDataAsync() => await BlobCache.InMemory.GetOrCreateObject(...);
public List<T> GetAllData() => GetAllDataAsync().Result;
```

This will cause deadlock. What have I done wrong?

**Edit1**: This code is running in a ASP.NET Web API

Comment: There are hundreds of questions regarding deadlocks due to using `.Result`, did you even search? A common solution is to use `GetAllDataAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, but this depends also on the `SynchronizationContext` but you did not add information on where this is being run.

Comment: embrace doing it all async or doing it all with Observables and you will have a much happier time :-)

Answer (score 2):

Akavache is designed for mobile and desktop applications and will perform very poorly in a server environment. Use Redis or memcached.